# how to bypass squid proxy with pac file?

Tags: proxy, squid, pac

I currently have Squid v3.5.20 installed on a Centos7 VM. The proxy is working well and blocking everything on the block ACL. My issue comes with the PAC file. I want to bypass the proxy for certain sites with the PAC file by return "DIRECT";. All the urls that are on the PAC file to return direct are still going via the proxy and being blocked. Any ideas on what is wrong?

PAC file bellow

```
    function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

    //  If the hostname matches the domains below, send direct (bypass proxy).
            if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".user.global.local"))
                return "DIRECT";

    //  If the URL matches, send direct.
            if (shExpMatch(url, "http://*.gotomeeting.com/*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "https://*.gotomeeting.com/*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "https://maps.google.com/*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "https://www.google.com/maps*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "http://maps.google.com/*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "http://www.google.com/maps*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "http://www.google.com/maps/*") ||
                shExpMatch(url, "https://www.google.com/maps/*"))
                return "DIRECT";

    //  If the requested website is hosted within the internal network, send direct.
            if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
                shExpMatch(host, "*.local") ||
                isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.0.0",  "255.255.0.0") ||
                isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0"))
                return "DIRECT";

                else{
                return "PROXY 192.168.1.100:3128"}

    }
```

Squid config

```
    #
    # Recommended minimum configuration:
    #

    # Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
    # Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
    # should be allowed
    #acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
    #acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
    acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
    acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
    #acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
    acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
    acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
    acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

    acl SSL_ports port 443
    acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
    acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
    acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
    acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
    acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
    acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
    acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
    acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
    acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
    acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
    acl CONNECT method CONNECT

    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    # Custom ACL DOMAINS Block Lists
    #__________________________________________________________________________________

    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    # Custom ACL Lists
    #__________________________________________________________________________________

    acl block_manuallist dstdomain "/etc/squid/squid-manual-blacklist.acl"
    acl allow_whitelist dstdomain "/etc/squid/squid-whitelist.acl"



    #
    # Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
    #
    # Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
    http_access deny !Safe_ports

    # Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
    http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

    # Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
    http_access allow localhost manager
    http_access deny manager

    # We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
    # web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
    # one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
    #http_access deny to_localhost

    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    # Custom HTTP ACCESS ALLOW DOMAINS Lists
    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    http_access allow allow_whitelist


    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    # Custom HTTP ACCESS ALLOW DOMAINS Lists
    #__________________________________________________________________________________

    http_access deny block_manuallist

    #__________________________________________________________________________________
    # Custom HTTP ACCESS ALLOW EXPRESSIONS/URLS Lists
    #__________________________________________________________________________________

    #http_access allow allow_whitelist_expressions
    #http_access allow allow_whitelist_urls





    # Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
    # Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
    # from where browsing should be allowed

    http_access allow localnet
    http_access allow localhost

    # And finally deny all other access to this proxy
    http_access deny all

    # Squid normally listens to port 3128
    http_port 3128

    # Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
    cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

    # Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
    coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

    #
    # Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
    #
    refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
    refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
    refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
    refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
    refresh_pattern -i \.(iso|avi|wav|mp3|mp4|mpeg|swf|flv|x-flv)$ 43200 90% 432000 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
    refresh_pattern -i \.(deb|rpm|exe|zip|tar|tgz|ram|rar|bin|ppt|doc|tiff)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
    refresh_pattern -i \.index.(html|htm)$ 0 40% 10080
    refresh_pattern -i \.(html|htm|css|js)$ 1440 40% 40320
    refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
    append_domain .user.global.local
    cache_effective_user squid
    cache_effective_group squid
```

Comment: Can you try and split your `if` block into individual statements; `if (shExpMatch(url,"*.mydomain.com/*")) {return "DIRECT";}` and see if that works instead.